# crontab multiple postgresql issue

Tags: bash, postgresql, cron

I'm trying to run a script (automation.sh) automated in crontab.
(I'm on Ubuntu 14.04).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

day=$(date +%F -d'yesterday')

cat /home/tomi/logs/$day |grep registration > /home/tomi/registrations/$day
cat /home/tomi/logs/$day |grep free_tree > /home/tomi/free_tree/$day
cat /home/tomi/logs/$day |grep super_tree > /home/tomi/super_tree/$day

psql -U hello -d postgres -c "\COPY registrations FROM '/home/tomi/registrations/$day' DELIMITER ' '";
psql -U hello -d postgres -c "\COPY free_tree FROM '/home/tomi/free_tree/$day' DELIMITER ' '";
psql -U hello -d postgres -c "\COPY super_tree FROM '/home/tomi/super_tree/$day' DELIMITER ' '";

psql -U hello -d postgres -f daily_active_users.sql > /home/tomi/tmp1
psql -U hello -d postgres -f daily_revenue.sql > /home/tomi/tmp2
```

If I run this script normally from the command line, then the last two lines generate tmp1 and tmp2 with data in them. (That's the expected result.)

However, if I run this very same script in crontab, everything works, but the last two lines generate empty files (tmp1 and tmp2).

The tricky thing is that when I break this script into two scripts (eg. automated.sh and automated2.sh) and run the last two lines in crontab 5 minutes later (via this automated2.sh script), tmp1 and tmp2 are generated correctly, with data in them.

Any idea, what can cause this?

Comment: does automated2.sh have any additional commands (eg, sourcing an env, full path to the *.sql files)? I could understand the single script failing on the last 2 lines if cron doesn't know where to find the *.sql files (assuming your crontab is running with the default bare bones env); in a nutshell ... where are the *sql files located and have you verified your scripts (when run by cron) know where to find the *sql files?

Comment: ah, shoot, you have right, full path is missing on the last two lines' .sql files! stupid mistake, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in the comments:
full path is missing on last two lines in automation.sh!
Thanks!